# Problem with using self-built GDAL in Docker

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gdal

I am trying to prepare an Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image with GDAL 3.2.2. This GDAL installation needs to have ECW support, which means I cannot use the pre-built gdal-bin package that can be installed using apt.

I can build and install GDAL with these specs in the Docker container. But when running a simple test command on a simple tiff file I get an error that I have no idea how to debug.

```
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.2.2, released 2021/03/05
$ gdalinfo test.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: test.tif
Size is 572, 577
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The steps I took was starting with a regular Ubuntu 22.04 Docker image. Installing prerequisites (gcc and stuff). Downloading the ECW SDK. Install that. Download the source of gdal 3.2.2. Configure the build to include ECW. Use the make file to build and then install.

If I do not use a self-built GDAL but rather install gdal-bin using apt directly, it works for the tiff file, but it would mean I have no ECW support.

I have also successfully built and used GDAL with ECW directly on Ubuntu 22.04 without Docker.

Does anyone know a solution for this or have any idea in which direction I could look to potentially debug it?

Comment: Does this answer offer anything? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/449991/154461

Comment: What should be the response of `gdalinfo test.tif` ? Share us your Dockerfile to test it

Comment: @RobertDavy Unfortunately no. The problems I am facing is before attempting to use GDAL through Python. The information there about the ECW SDK having multiple licenses are correct though.

Comment: @JRichardsz The response should be the metadata information about the file. Things like the coordinate system, bounds and bands.

Unforunately, I cannot share the Dockerfile because I do not have one. The current workflow is to save the whole image that is properly set up as a new image and copy it to a new system.

Comment: Did the VonC answer helped you?

Comment: I have left a response in the comments of that answer.

Comment: Alas, I am afraid that you do not have any other choice besides properly debugging your issue. Build GDAL with `-O0 -g` flags and launch `gdb --args gdalinfo test.tif`, then type `run` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the same process using a dedicated Docker iage like [`klokantech/gdal`](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/klokantech/gdal)

```
docker run -ti --rm -v $(pwd):/data klokantech/gdal gdalinfo yourfile.tif
```

> The container is minimal (about 350 MB) and is compiled from latest stable GDAL with MrSID, ECW and JP2KAK drivers.

Since the [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/klokan/bfd4a07e8072ffae4bb6) is quite old, you can rebuild your own image from it, making sure you get the right version of GDAL.

This Dockerfile does install GDAL with ECW support, which is what you need.
However, it has a few potential issues:

1. The Dockerfile uses Debian 7 as the base image, which is quite old. You mentioned you are using Ubuntu 22.04 as your base image, which is much newer.
2. The Dockerfile installs GDAL version 1.11.1, but you want to install GDAL 3.2.2.
3. The Dockerfile requires private URLs to download the ECW and other SDKs. You will need to replace these with the actual URLs where these SDKs can be downloaded.

To use this Dockerfile, you would need to make a few changes:

1. Change the base image from Debian 7 to Ubuntu 22.04 (or possibly an updated version of Debian if you prefer that).
2. Change the GDAL version from 1.11.1 to 3.2.2.
3. Replace the placeholders in the `SDKS_URL` environment variable with the actual URLs where the ECW and other SDKs can be downloaded.

Once you have made these changes, you should be able to build a Docker image that meets your requirements.

Something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libepsilon-dev \
    libexpat1-dev \
    libfreexl-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libgif-dev \
    libhdf4-alt-dev \
    libhdf5-serial-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    liblcms2-dev \
    liblzma-dev \
    libnetcdf-dev \
    libpcre3-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libpodofo-dev \
    libpoppler-dev \
    libproj-dev \
    libspatialite-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libtbb2 \
    libwebp-dev \
    libxerces-c-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    netcdf-bin \
    poppler-utils \
    python3-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    unzip

ENV SDKS_URL http://your.url.here
ENV ECW_VERSION 3.3
ENV ECW_DATE 2006-09-06
ENV ECW_NAME libecwj2-$ECW_VERSION
ENV ECW_DIR /usr/local/src/$ECW_NAME

RUN curl -s $SDKS_URL/$ECW_NAME-$ECW_DATE.zip -o $ECW_DIR.zip \
    && unzip -q $ECW_DIR.zip -d /usr/local/src \
    && cd $ECW_DIR \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    && make \
    && make install

# Remove MRSID and KAKADU if not needed
# ...

ENV GDAL_VERSION 3.2.2
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src \
    && curl -s http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/$GDAL_VERSION/gdal-$GDAL_VERSION.tar.gz \
    | tar xz -C /usr/local/src

WORKDIR /usr/local/src/gdal-$GDAL_VERSION

RUN ./configure \
    --prefix=/usr/local \
    --without-libtool \
    --with-ecw=/usr/local \
    --with-epsilon \
    --with-libkml \
    --with-liblzma \
    --with-podofo \
    --with-poppler \
    --with-python \
    --with-spatialite \
    --with-threads \
    --with-webp \
    && make \
    && make install \
    && ldconfig
```

You will need to replace `http://your.url.here` with the actual URL where you are hosting the ECW SDK. And adjust its version (see [GDAL wiki ECW](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW))

Also, note that I have removed the installation steps for MRSID and KAKADU as I assumed you do not need those. If you do, you will need to put them back in and adjust the URLs and versions as necessary.

---

[Dirk Eddelbuettel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143305/dirk-eddelbuettel) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76323211/problem-with-using-self-built-gdal-in-docker/76373397#comment134673299_76373397):

> Alternatively, if you are familiar with building a `.deb` you can modify the existing binary package `gdal-bin` (and `libgdal-dev` etc) which I had done in the past to add TiileDB support. The Launchpad site by Canonical can build and host the binaries for various releases; I use this regularly for "local" version of updated Debian packages (and just did so on the weekend for `mlpack`).
> The `.deb` files then go rather easily into your (much quicker !!) Docker build step.

Here, instead of building GDAL directly from source, this approach involves modifying the existing Debian packages (`gdal-bin`, `libgdal-dev`, etc.) to include ECW support, and then building `.deb` packages from those modified sources. You can then install these `.deb` packages in your Docker container.

This approach has a couple of advantages:

1. **Faster Docker builds**: Building GDAL from source can take a long time. If you have pre-built `.deb` packages, you can install them with `apt` in your Dockerfile, which is much faster.
2. **Easier maintenance**: Once you have the `.deb` packages, you can use them in multiple Dockerfiles without having to repeat the complex GDAL build process.

The basic steps to follow are:

1. Modify the GDAL source code to include ECW support. This is similar to what you were doing before, but instead of building GDAL directly, you will build a `.deb` package.
2. Build the `.deb` packages. This can be done using a tool like [`dpkg-buildpackage`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-buildpackage.1.html).
3. Upload the `.deb` packages to a repository. You can use a personal package archive (PPA) on Launchpad for this.
4. In your Dockerfile, add the PPA to your list of repositories and install the GDAL packages with `apt`.

Your Dockerfile would include something like:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qq -y --no-install-recommends install \
    software-properties-common \
    apt-transport-https \
    curl

# Add your PPA to the list of repositories
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:your/launchpad/ppa

# Update the package list and install the modified GDAL packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gdal-bin \
    libgdal-dev \
    # other GDAL packages as needed
```

Replace `ppa:your/launchpad/ppa` with the actual PPA where you are hosting the `.deb` packages.

Keep in mind that this is a high-level overview. Modifying Debian packages, building `.deb` packages, and using Launchpad are all complex tasks that require a good understanding of the Debian packaging system. If you're not already familiar with these processes, you may want to stick with the first approach.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are familiar with building a .deb you can modify the existing binary package `gdal-bin` (and `libgdal-dev` etc) which I had done in the past to add TiileDB support.  The [Launchpad site by Canonical](https://launchpad.net) can build _and host_ the binaries for various releases; I use this regularly for "local" version of updated Debian packages (and just did so on the weekend for `mlpack`).  The .deb files then go rather easily into your (much quicker !!) Docker build step.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and expanded on the possible process.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

Looking at the procedures in the given Dockerfile, it is very similar to the commands I would run to build GDAL with ECW. In my mind this procedure could work due to the minor differences between their and my procedure, but I also predict the success chance to be fairly low due to the similarities after the OS, GDAL version and ECW SDK versions are changed to the versions I need.

Due to that, my current work prioritization doesn't allow me to give this method a go. But I might attempt this in a week or two if no better solution is provided

Comment: @Minghai Sure, I wanted to describe both approaches to be complete (thanks to Dirk's contribution). Let me know what will work for you.